# Show $p_1,p_2,p_3$ lies on a straight line in $\mathbb R^3$ if and only if $p_3 -p_1$ and $p_2-p_1$ are linearly dependent.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $p_i=(a_i,b_i,c_i)^T$ for $i = 1,2,3$ denote three different elements in $\mathbb R^3$.

Show $p_1,p_2,p_3$ lies on a straight line in $\mathbb R^3$ if and only if $p_3 -p_1$ and $p_2-p_1$ are linearly dependent.

I've proven $\Rightarrow$ with the following reasoning: a line is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ with basis a single element $u$. So if $p_1,p_2,p_3$ are elements of this subspace, then every linear combination must be also.

However, I cannot prove the other direction.

Comment: you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, not every line is a subspace, unfortunately. :(

Note all lines are of the form $\{\vec{a} + c\vec{v} \mid c\in \mathbb{R}\}$ for some $\vec{a}, \, \vec{v}\in \mathbb{R}^3$, and any such set is a line. How about trying to show that $p_3-p_1$ and $p_2-p_1$ are linearly dependent iff $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$ can all be written in this form?

Comment: Give an example ?

Comment: Any line which doesn't pass through 0 is not a subspace.

Comment: Is any line on this form by definition or ?

Comment: @muller I suppose it depends on your definition of a line. I'm not aware of a canonical definition. To be sure, this is as good a definition as any.